# How to look up an entity from Google Cloud Datastore that has numeric value key in PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The following code was run on Google App Engine Flex env.

For example: the key is **Key(Task,"t12")**. I can look it up in PHP using the following syntax:

```
$key = $datastore->key('Task', "t12");
$task = $datastore->lookup($key);
```

However, if the key is **Key(Task, 12)**. I cannot look it up with the syntax:

```
$key = $datastore->key('Task', 12);
$task = $datastore->lookup($key);
```

Or even

```
$key = $datastore->key('Task', intval("12"));
$task = $datastore->lookup($key);
```

I tried the query again and it worked well for the first entity (which was created in code). However, for the 3 following entities (which was created using the console) only the last entity worked. I recognized there a different in the first column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation

> Assigning identifiers In addition to a kind, each entity has an
>   identifier, assigned when the entity is created. Because it is part of
>   the entity's key, the identifier is associated permanently with the
>   entity and cannot be changed. It can be assigned in either of two
>   ways:
>
> 1.Your application can specify its own key name string for the entity.
>
> 2.You can have Firestore in Datastore mode automatically assign the entity an integer numeric ID.
>
> 3.Assigning your own numeric ID which is integer

Therefore I used case 3, and you used case 1. In case 1 you should search for a string because you set a key name when you inserted using console, which is of type string. When I inserted an entry using client libraries I used my own numeric ID, which is of type int.

name=12 and name="12" are two strings  which are not the same

Comment: Thanks for yours answer but I have figured real the problem. When I created an entity in code (like you did) the key column was id=33. However, when I created an entity on the console, it was name=12 (see the edited post). When look up the entity in the first case it worked perfectly, but for my case it is only worked if the value of the key has character. I'm new to the technology so I really dont no what is the different between name and id for key.

Comment: So could you show me how to search the case name=12 and name="12". I have tried:
```
$key = $datastore->key('Task', strval("12"));
$task = $datastore->lookup($key);
```
and 
```
$key = $datastore->key('Task', strval(12));
$task = $datastore->lookup($key);
```
and both is not worked for me.

Comment: it seems that the name does not accept only int values, I could not search it either